# AVR Is it possible to address IO ports indirectly

Tags: assembly, avr

I have a question:

Is it possible to address the I/O ports of the AVR controllers indirectly like:

```
out r16, r19
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official [instruction manual](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-0856-avr-instruction-set-manual.pdf), unfortunately the instructions `in` and `out` doesn't support indirect addressing. But you can use the load (`ld`, `lds` and `ldd`) and store (`st`, `sts` and `std`) instructions instead. They are usually used for I/O operations on more complex (with more peripherals) AVR micro controllers, but should work on I/O addresses lesser than `0x60` too.

*Quote from the instruction manual:*

> **Note:**  Some complex AVR Microcontrollers have more peripheral units
> than can be supported within the64 locations reserved in the opcode
> for I/O direct addressing. The extended I/O memory from address 64to
> 255 can only be reached by data addressing, not I/O addressing.

*These simple indirect addressing example (GNU Assembler) should work:*

```
/* Load DDRA I/O address into RAMPX (r26, r27) */
clr r27;
ldi r26, 0x21;
/* Store value 0xFF into specific (DDRA) register */
ldi r16, 0xFF;
st X, r16;
```

The above example use DDRA I/O port from an ATMEGA2560. For the correct I/O address consult the datasheet from the specific device.